# ASP.Net machinekey, validationkey, and decryptionkey - key lengths

Tags: asp.net

What are the default key lengths that are generated when leaving the ValidationKey and DecryptionKey at their defaults?   For example:

```
<machineKey decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" ... />
```

I have not been able to find this documented anywhere on MSDN.
I would like to generate a static machine key and keep it in line with the defaults.

Answer (score 9):

This [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx) page talks about the machineKey web.config element:

> "For SHA1, set the validationKey to 64 bytes (128 hexadecimal characters). 
>   For AES, set the decryptionKey to 32 bytes (64 hexadecimal characters). 
>   For 3DES, set the decryptionKey to 24 bytes (48 hexadecimal characters)."

Another [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9(VS.71).aspx) page has additional info:

> "validationKey specifies a manually
>   assigned validation key. This value
>   must be manually set to ensure
>   consistent configuration across a
>   network of Web servers (a Web farm).
>   The key must be a minimum of 40
>   characters (20 bytes) and a maximum of
>   128 characters (64 bytes) long. If
>   keys shorter than the maximum length
>   are used, they should be created by a
>   truly random means, such as by using
>   RNGCryptoServiceProvider. The
>   recommended key length is 128
>   hexadecimal characters. If you add the
>   IsolateApps modifier to the
>   validationKey value, ASP.NET generates
>   a unique encrypted key for each
>   application using each application's
>   application ID."
>
> "decryptionKey specifies a manually
>   assigned key. This value must be
>   manually set to a string of
>   hexadecimal characters to ensure
>   consistent configuration across a Web
>   farm. The key should be 16 characters
>   in length when using DES encryption
>   and 48 characters in length when using
>   Triple DES encryption. If keys shorter
>   than the maximum length are used, they
>   should be created by a truly random
>   means, such as by using
>   RNGCryptoServiceProvider. ASP.NET can
>   use Triple DES only on computers on
>   which 128-bit encryption is available.
>   If you add the IsolateApps modifier to
>   the decryptionKey value, ASP.NET
>   generates a unique encrypted key for
>   each application using each
>   application's application ID."

Comment: Thanks, I did see these documents.  No mention of what the autogenerate defaults are though.

Comment: It doesn't say explicitly, but I think the article implies that the  default is the maximum length.

Comment: For SHA1, what should the decryptionKey length be set to?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following Link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations